# Why SSD performance is not better than HDD in specific cases?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I am using MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 22.04. All my tables are MyISAM. Recently I bought 1 TB SSD Samsung 980 PRO to replace the existing 7200 rpm HDD in order to boost read performance. My test machine is one old Dell Optiplex 3050 micro with Core i3 (6th gen) and 8 GB RAM. So the machine configuration with HDD and SSD is absolutely the same. So is the test database. Before upgrading to SSD I did a lot of tests with HDD. I run the same tests with SSD. In some cases SSD performance for query executions is far better, in other just a little better, but there are cases when it is slower.

So far I thought that hard drive read operations are the bottleneck, but now I doubt it since the fact that the performance of the configuration with SSD is not better (or even worse) in some of the cases listed below.

Using KDiskMark shows following comparison of Read [MB/s] for both storage devices:

| Test | SSD | HDD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SEQ1M Q8T1 | 3044 | 84 |
| SEQ1M Q1T1 | 2114 | 84 |
| RND4K Q32T1 | 660 | 0.7 |
| RND4K Q1T1 | 66 | 0.3 |

The query joins the statistical table `h_cell` with a temporary table `tmptab`, which is populated with a list of objects `cell` for a user-selected cluster definition. The result set is a table with a number of KPIs, which are aggregated to cluster level values for each date of the reporting interval. The reference between both tables is `cell`. The statistical table `h_cell` contains daily values for a number of counters for each `cell` for each day. This table contains 2 years of statistics for about 50k cells for each day.

Data in `h_cell` was imported with `LOAD DATA INFILE` in chronological order. After importing `ANALYZE TABLE` was run. No changes to table happened afterwards.

```
SET @DATE1='2019-04-01';SET @DATE2='2019-06-30';
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptab(cell CHAR(8) NOT NULL,INDEX `Cell` (`Cell`) USING BTREE) Engine=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO tmptab SELECT cell FROM clusters_cust WHERE cluster='cluster3k';
SELECT 'cluster3k' AS Cluster,Time,
ROUND(SUM(counter1)/sum(counter1+counter2)*100,2) as 'KPI1',
.........
FROM h_cell
INNER JOIN tmptab ON tmptab.cell = h_cell.cell
WHERE time >= @DATE1 AND time <= @DATE2
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmptab;
```

Below you can find benchmarks for execution time for different scenarios. No caching was implemented for benchmarked queries.

1. Experiments with a small cluster of 60 cells. Here SSD performance is much better than HDD

- 1 month: SSD vs HDD - **1s** vs **14s**
- 3 months:  SSD vs HDD - **3s** vs **40s**
- 6 months:  SSD vs HDD - **10s** vs **3m 01s**

2. Experiments with a medium-sized cluster of 3k cells. SSD performance is just marginally better than HDD one for the 1 month experiment. The huge execution time for HDD for 3 and 6 months is partly due to wrong selection of index by optimizer. This will be a topic for another thread.

- 1 month: SSD vs HDD - **53s** vs **59s**
- 3 months #1:  SSD vs HDD - **2m 25s** vs **33m 30s** (HDD wrong index `PRIMARY` was used; SSD is using the same index)
- 3 months #2:  SSD vs HDD - **2m 25s** vs **2m 49s** (HDD version was forced to use the correct index `Time`; SSD is using `PRIMARY` index; forcing SSD to use `Time` gives very similar execution time)
- 6 months:  SSD vs HDD - **4m 50s** vs **70m** (same situation with the wrong index)

3. Experiments with a large cluster of 20k cells. Here SSD performance is in most cases worse than HDD one

- 1 month: SSD vs HDD - **3m 13s** vs **3m 10s**
- 3 months:  SSD vs HDD - **9m 59s** vs **9m 45s**
- 6 months:  SSD vs HDD - **19m 37s** vs **20m 20s**

`EXPLAIN` for a cluster of 3k cells and 3 months reporting interval (with the wrong index - point '3 months #1' from above):

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                   | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tmptab | NULL       | index | Cell                | Cell    | 32      | NULL                  | 3000 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h_cell | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY,Time,eNodeB | PRIMARY | 32      | ee_4g_hua.tmptab.cell |  671 |     7.94 | Using index condition                        |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

`EXPLAIN` for a cluster of 3k cells and 3 months reporting interval (with the forced index - point '3 months #2' from above):

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                   | rows    | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h_cell | NULL       | range | Time          | Time | 3       | NULL                  | 3104736 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tmptab | NULL       | ref   | Cell          | Cell | 32      | ee_4g_hua.h_cell.Cell |       1 |   100.00 | Using index           |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------+
```

More details about `h_cell` table:

```
CREATE TABLE h_cell (
  Time date NOT NULL,
  Cell char(8) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  LocalCI tinyint NOT NULL,
  counter1 int DEFAULT NULL,
  counter2 int DEFAULT NULL,
  ...................
  counter860 int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Cell,Time) USING BTREE,
  KEY Time (Time,LocalCI) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

```
SHOW INDEXES IN h_cell;
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| h_cell |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | Cell        | A         |       58257 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| h_cell |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | Time        | A         |    39090988 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| h_cell |          1 | Time     |            1 | Time        | A         |         730 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| h_cell |          1 | Time     |            2 | LocalCI     | A         |       15081 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

```
mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS IN xxx;
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+
| Name          | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows     | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time          | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options     | Comment |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+
| h_cell        | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    | 39090988 |           1969 | 76975355392 | 281474976710655 |   1736918016 |         0 |              1 | 2024-03-19 22:30:50 | 2024-03-19 23:51:03 | 2024-03-20 00:17:21 | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |     NULL | row_format=DYNAMIC |         |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+
```

Comment: myisam is very very old and should be urgently switched to innido

Comment: @nbk I will not do this. InnoDb doesn't suit my needs for fast imports (most importantly) and smaller footprint. My database is mostly reads with once a day huge imports, which with InnoDb are taking ages (x20 times slower than MyISAM). More likely is to switch to MariaDb, where MyISAM still have some weight, while this engine in MySQL is totally abandoned.

Comment: @Ivaylo Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after benchmarks completed and minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide higher performance suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: 20 times slower i doubt it and you can always make a inndb table with all data and test

Comment: What is the question?  Perhaps: "Why aren't my queries running a lot faster?"  To help with that, we need to see the queries, the table sizes and (assuming still MyISAM), the value of `key_buffer_size`.

Comment: Since your switch to InnoDB resulted in terrible performance, let's examine the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value that you used. (It should have been 5G, with `key_buffer_size` lowered to 20M.)

Comment: Also... Are the daily imports appending to the existing table?  Or replacing all the data in the table?  (There is a very fast technique for the latter, especially for InnoDB.)

Comment: `INT` takes 4 bytes -- could your counters be smaller?  (This would help each Engine.)

Comment: @WilsonHauck OS is Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.4. RAM is 8 GB DDR4 2133 MHz. CPU Intel Core i3-6100T CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4 (2 Cores, 4 Threads). SSD is Samsung 980 PRO 1TB connected to PCIe 3.0 x2 NVMe 1.3 (I think). Need to say that the server is just a test server, so I switch it on only when I have something to test, so It is never up for 24 hours. There are no other users than me. Software that is loaded is the defaults for Ubuntu Desktop plus some services like Samba, xrdp, Python and MySQL of course.

Comment: @WilsonHauck In this comment you can find the outputs of the MySQL commands that you requested. I cannot run STATUS as it is not accepted by server. [link](https://justpaste.it/g6kok); [link](https://justpaste.it/ejth8); [link](https://justpaste.it/39o0e)

Comment: @WilsonHauck In this comment you can find the outputs of the Linux commands that you requested. I am not sure how to export the result of htop, so it is not included. [link](https://justpaste.it/equj1); [link](https://justpaste.it/dvj45); [link](https://justpaste.it/frdhh); [link](https://justpaste.it/b2zlb); [link](https://justpaste.it/fiqhl); [link](https://justpaste.it/1qjj7)

Comment: @nbk In fact it was even 60 times slower. You can refer to following stackoverflow thread by me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77836058/improve-speed-of-load-data-infile-for-innodb-in-mysql-8). My idea was to create an InnoDb table, to fill it with big amount of data, so that to test the read performance. Unfortunately importing speed was so poor that I abanondend the idea of testing InnoDb.

Comment: @RickJames I will answer your questions as comments to your answer below. Regarding InnoDb performance I created one thread on stackoverflow, where you gave a lot of ideas. Please refer to following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77836058/improve-speed-of-load-data-infile-for-innodb-in-mysql-8).

Answer (score 1):

Tentative answer...  [Please answer the Comments so I can elaborate.]

- The benchmarks are designed to stress I/O
- Some of your cases can use the caching of MySQL to avoid much of the I/O; some cannot.
- The caching opportunities of the two engines are not the same; several things may need changing when the engine is changed.
- 860 4-byte INTs takes 3440 bytes plus overhead.  This stresses each engine in different ways.
- Deleting and adding rows to MyISAM can lead to fragmentation that gets worse and worse.
- Deleting and adding rows to InnoDB has other problems.
- Building and maintaining [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables), if appropriate, would speed up both engines on both disk types.

Comment: I need to clarify that statictics in my table are chronologically ordered, because I imported the raw data in chronological order. As far as I know this helps the optimizer. After ```LOAD DATA INFILE``` operations I run ```ANALYZE TABLE``` AND ```OPTIMIZE TABLE``` (which I guess was not needed). No deletions or other alterations were done after importing.

Comment: I haven't used any specific benchmarking tools. I just created a few different versions 
 of clusters with 60, 3k and 20k cells and run the queries. I guess no caching was used, because between runs I was restarting the server and execution times between different versions of clusters (for example with 3k objects) were similar. Even when I run after system restart the same cluster for the same reporting period (absolutely the same query) execution time was almost the same, so no OS/disk caching was used.

Comment: The value of ```key_buffer_size``` is 16777216. It is not sufficient, but the same value was used in both cases - with HDD and SSD. Regarding the table size you can find one addition to my question at the end (```SHOW TABLE STATUS```).

Comment: Daily imports are always appending to the table. There are no deletions in this table. Very rarely when imported data is not integral it might happen to reload it with ```INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE```.

Comment: I prefer to keep ```INT``` because sometimes counters with usual two-digits values might explode to huge numbers in some circumstances and I cannot risk to have statistics truncated.

Comment: @Ivaylo - What was `innodb_buffer_pool_size` set to during the InnoDB timing tests?

Comment: ```innodb_buffer_pool_size``` was 6 GB out of the total 8 GB RAM. I will do the timing tests again now with SSD drive.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions to consider for improving speed of LOADING TABLES.

```
innodb_io_capacity=900  # from 200 to use more of available IOPS.
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT  # from fsync - O_DIRECT is used on most Linux servers.
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% CPU cycles used for function.
table_open_cache_instances=1  # from 16 you only have 2 CORES.
bulk_insert_buffer_size=64M  # from 1G to conserve RAM
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=10000  # from 150000 (seconds) for 1 second delay when busy
innodb_old_blocks_pct=1  # from 37 percent of buffer_pool_size set aside
sort_buffer_size=1M  # from 16M until you see sort_merge_passes > 1 per hour
temptable_max_mmap=86M  # from 1G for 1% of RAM to conserve RAM
temptable_max_ram=86M  # from 1G for 1% of RAM to conserve RAM
innod_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 percent anytime you are pushing HEAVY INSERTS.
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # from 0 to record all needed on EXTENT in one sweep.
innodb_stats_auto_recalc=OFF  # not needed during loading - ANALYZE table when done loading.
innodb_stats_persistent=OFF  # not needed during loading - ANALYZE table when done loading.
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G  # from 128M for higher speed loading of data (~ 62% of 8G)
```

There may be additional opportunities.  View my profile, please.

Observation:
Most people put all LOG's in one folder /log we see a couple of yours in /var/lib which would not be typical.
datadir used to always be in a DATA folder.

Comment: This looks like a fantastic summary. I will give it a try. And what about ```innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit```? In a lot of places one can find suggestions to change the default 1 to 0 or 2 in order to improve importing speed. In the experiments in my other thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77836058/improve-speed-of-load-data-infile-for-innodb-in-mysql-8) I didn't experience any improvement.

Comment: I tried most of your suggestions. Unfortunately I was not able to wait for ```LOAD DATA INFILE``` to finish, because of excessive importing time. The batch that I was loading was with 3 mil rows. The target table was empty with keys disabled. For MyISAM version of the table the loading took about 5 minutes. Now with InnoDb I canceled loading after 1 hour 44 minutes. Judging by the size of ```.ibd``` file loading was not more than half way through, so I can estimate loading time of 3+ hours, which is unacceptable.

Comment: If you tried my suggestions one at a time, there would be no improvement.  What do you mean by most of the suggestions?

Comment: Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE yourdestinationtable; for a look at the scope of your load.